# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . D3 Tooltips

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having trouble with this error. I am trying to add a tooltip to a d3 element. Please let me know if you see where I am going wrong. The error says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . on the .append
```

This is my code:

```
g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
      .attr("r", 8);
      // Here we add an SVG title element the contents of which is effectively rendered in a tooltip
      .append("svg:title")
        .text(function(d, i) { return "My color is " + d[2]; });
```

Comment: There is a semicolon right after setting `.attr("r", 8)` ending the statement. Hence the error about the next line starting with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, You have a Syntax Error

```
.attr("r", 8);
```

You cannot have the `;` and then append. `;` actually ends the statement.
Here is the correct code.

```
g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
      .attr("r", 8)
      // Here we add an SVG title element the contents of which is effectively rendered in a tooltip
      .append("svg:title")
        .text(function(d, i) { return "My color is " + d[2]; });
```

**Note** : I think you have an error in the selection as well, in `g.selectAll("scatter-dots")` what does `scatter-dots` refers to ? a `class` or an `id`. If it is a `class` then it has to be `.scatter-dots` or if it is an `id` then it has to be `#scatter-dots`.